# Google maps resize

Tags: javascript, google-maps, resize

I try to make the google maps resize as i  resize my browser but it seems that no matter what i try the size remains the same. I have also try to change the height and width with an external CSS when the browser goes under 786px but i got nothing. Any help:

Here is my code

```
   <style>

    #map_canvas 
   {width:600px;
   height:400px;
   position: relative; 
   float: center;
 }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

    <script>
    var map, marker;
    var lng = <?php echo json_encode($lng); ?>;
    var lat = <?php echo json_encode($lat); ?>;
    var desc= <?php echo json_encode($desc); ?>;

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

      function initialize() {
        var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');

        var map_options = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(xxxx, yyyy),
          zoom: 15,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
         map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options);
        for (i = 0; i < lng.length; i++) {
        AddLocations(lat[i], lng[i]);

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(desc[i]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));

            }
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
     var center = map.getCenter();
     google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
     map.setCenter(center); 
    });

        function addMarker(location) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            map: map
        });
    }


    function AddLocations(lat, lng) {
           pos  = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
           addMarker(pos);
    }

    </script>
```

And i display it with the following code

```
   <div id="map_canvas"  ></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your *map-canvas* width and height values **from fixed (px) to dynamic (%)**, because now, even though the window changes in dimensions, your div keeps its fixed size. You also need to change the html and body elements' width to 100% .

Comment: when i do it in 80% both i lose the whole map from my page

Comment: To use percentage sizing, you need to specify the size of all the parents of the div up to html.  See [this page in Mike Williams' v2 tutorial](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic19.htm)

Comment: Did you set the html and body height to **100%**?

Comment: thaks that was the problem i did not use percentages in the html and body!!